# Lock screen without using physical button Android 10

Tags: lock-screens

I am looking for a good way to lock the screen on my phone without using a physical button (the botton is on the edge of dying so I am preserving it for turning the phone on).

I would like to lock the phone by movement or tapping somewhere on the touch screen.

(I prefer it if this can be done without using external apps but if necessary I prefer free ones without ads.)

The f-Droid app [FLock](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/ryey.flock/) seems like it would have been ideal, but it crashes before I even have the chance to test it ().

Comment: Nova launcher can do this. You can set up gestures to lock screen and select suitable lock screen methods (see under advanced settings). I don't recall if this is available with free version (I think it should be), since I bought the pro almost immediately. Been using this launcher for many years now and this is my go - to method before I root device. Is your device rooted? Please include that in the question by [edit]ing. Rooted devices have many more options

Comment: I tried and you cannot use the gesture settings in the free version of Nova launcher. (Device is not rooted, but I might be willing to do it to solve this problem.)

Comment: So this needs paid version! Upto you to try this out or root. If you decide to root then there are some Xposed modules that make this easy but it depends on your comfort level with such things and also your device. All devices do not play the same. To be fair, there is a learning curve if you aren't familiar with such stuff

Comment: Since your home button is dying and it's much needed in the rooting process, I would suggest you go for launcher method or wait for answers

Comment: Not an answer to the question but anyone interested in the question above will probably need to know the following urgently: In order to avoid being locked out of your phone just because the physical buttons aren't working anymore you should immediately turn on USB debugging so that you have options to turn on your phone using your pc if you otherwise get locked out. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18103158/7238575.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a built-in option that comes with Android 10 which allows you to lock the screen without using the bottom.

In your phone settings, go to "Accessibility" and enable "accessibility menu".

This will now put an icon on the the right side of your navigation bar. Pressing on the icon will bring up a menu, with one of the options as "lock screen". Pressing on that will lock your screen just like pressing the power button would. You also have the option to power off the phone in that same menu.

See screenshot below.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The app [Lock](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/name.seguri.android.lock/) works but a downside is that afterwards the phone cannot be unlocked using a fingerprint, only using the pattern. (Also it is not available from within other apps. So a movement activated solution would be better.)